# How to set permissions to only POST data for API (React + Django Rest Framework)

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm writing my blog with React as Frontend and DRF as a backend. I've made two API's - one is made for posts and second one is made for data contained in Contact Form. To obtain posts I'm using axios and the Django permission is set to `IsAdmin` - it means only admin can change post and this is fine.

The second one is a problem - if I change a permission to `AllowAny` it causes that Anonymous user can POST their data and... they can view it. If I change it to `IsAdminUser` none of users can POST their data. I need to know how I can store people's data safe (they can only POST data, and they are NOT allowed to view my API for contact form.)

Contact.js

```
const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <section>
      <Formik
        validate
        initialValues={{
          firstName: "",
          email: "",
        }}
        onSubmit={values => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            axios
              .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/questions/", values)
              .then(res => {
                alert("Sent", res.data);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                alert(err);
              });
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          }, 500);
        }}
        render={() => (
          <Form>
            <label htmlFor="firstName">Name</label>
            <Field name="firstName" placeholder="Name" required />

            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <Field
              name="email"
              placeholder="email@acme.com"
              type="email"
              required
            />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </Form>
        )}
      />
    </section>
  );
};
```

api.py

```
class QuestionsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Questions.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]

    serializer_class = QuestionsSerializer
```

I've mentioned before I can't change `permission_classes` to `permissions.AllowAny` because everyone can view a list of people who have submited my contact form. And I can't change it to `IsAdminUser` because contact form doesn't work then.

The question: is there any function or class that allow anonymous user to POST their data without permission to view my API?

Answer (score 0):

You could derive your view from `APIView` insetad and only implement a post method, like this:

```py
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class QuestionsViewSet(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = QuestionsSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'status': 'OK'})
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Reference: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom permission class,

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission

class PostOnlyPermissions(BasePermssion):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if self.action in ('create', ): // for POST method the action in DRF is create
            return True
        return False
```

And then simply call permission class in ViewSets

```
class QuestionsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (PostOnlyPermissions, )
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it in neariest future.